# Make wxPDFView library

Tags: c++, pdf, wxwidgets

Make wxpdfview lib, how to make it. 
After git clone https://github.com/TcT2k/wxPDFView.git and aftre making pdfium library, using cmake-gui i make the makefiles. (See all process at https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=44130).

Then with make take ..

> a@a-desktop ~/wxPDFView/libs $ make [ 7%] Building CXX object
>   CMakeFiles/wxPDFView.dir/src/PDFView.cpp.o In file included from
>   /home/a/wxPDFView/include/private/PDFViewImpl.h:27:0, from
>   /home/a/wxPDFView/src/PDFView.cpp:11:
>   /home/a/wxPDFView/include/private/PDFViewBookmarks.h:25:2: error:
>   ‘CPDF_BookmarkTree’ does not name a type

Any idea how to make?

Comment: did you try to contact the author of the library? Also it would be nice to mention: OS/toolkit, wx version, which compiler do you use? Thank you.

Comment: BTW, TCT is a subscriber on the wx ML's and I'm sure he also has an account on wx forum web site. You can try to send an e-mail about the issue to wx-users/wx-dev ML and he will be able to help. Just mention all that info in the post.

Comment: Mint Linux, wxWidgets3.0.3, gcc compiler. Thank you.